# Как первому выбранному элементу option select убрать &nbsp;?

Tags: javascript, php, html, веб-программирование

### Как при первом выбранному элементу select option value убрать пробел?

Именно **первому**

Кратко: Выбранные селекторы записываются в другой input, необходимо убрать пробел первому селектору.

```html
<script>
  function fn(sel) {
    var a = [],
      i = 0,
      b;
    for (; b = sel.options[i++];) {
      if (b.selected) a.push(b.text)
    };
    document.getElementById('rez').value = a;
  }
</script>


<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
  <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" id="genre" multiple="multiple" onchange="fn(this)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Боевик">&nbsp;Боевик</option>
    <option value="Драма ">&nbsp;Драма</option>
    <option value="Детектив ">&nbsp;Детектив</option>
    <option value="Комедия ">&nbsp;Комедия</option>
    <option value="Криминал ">&nbsp;Криминал</option>
    <option value="Мелодрама ">&nbsp;Мелодрама</option>
    <option value="Мультфильм ">&nbsp;Мультфильм</option>
    <option value="На реальных событиях ">&nbsp;На реальных событиях</option>
    <option value="Приключения ">&nbsp;Приключения</option>
    <option value="Триллер ">&nbsp;Триллер</option>
    <option value="Ужасы ">&nbsp;Ужасы</option>
    <option value="Фантастика ">&nbsp;Фантастика</option>
  </select>
</div>

<input id="rez" val="" name="genre" type="text" />
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код текстом, а не изображением, чтобы отвечающим было легче копировать и тестировать фрагменты.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, понял

Comment: `a[0] = a[0].trim();` перед `document.getElementById('rez').value = a;`

Comment: @InDevX, а куда это вставить? После `document.getElementById('rez').value = a;` не работает

Comment: @InDevX, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

`a[0] = a[0].trim();` перед `document.getElementById('rez').value = a;`